# Issue with parallax/smooth-scolling and mouse wheel scrolling of Bootstrap modal popup windows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I am having issue with parallax/smooth-scolling and mouse wheel scrolling of Bootstrap modal popup windows.
The Bootstrap modal popup appears when user clicks "Learn More" button.
The modal popup window have the scrollbar. The issue is that user is not able to scroll using mouse wheel because that event is intercepted by parallax/smooth-scolling script.

I am not able to insert code here because the amount of code is too big.
The issue can be reproduced on this [website](http://spectrawine.com/).

Is it possible to solve this issue with adding custom javascript to the website?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue stems from adding `parallax-3d` to the body tag which is adding an `onscroll` event listener to your popups. I can see this from inspecting the events for the popup elements in developer tools.

I would suggest adding `parallax-3d` to `main-container`.

```
<div class="main-container parallax-3d">
```

---

Edit: Ok, so the `parallax-3d` library adds for all elements in the body, irrespective of placement.

I just removed the scroll events for the modals and it works.

Try this to remove scroll events.

```
$('.foundry_modal').unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately it does not help.

Comment: Where should I add your code?
I added to script.js and it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: `scripts.js` loads before `parallax.js` so it would readd the events. It needs to be after that. I'd put it after all the js files you've got there. Also as a tip, I'd look at bundling many of your js files together as it's just so many http calls that would slow down initial loading of the site.

Comment: I added the code directly to the html after all scripts and still it does not unbind scroll event from modal popups.

Comment: I added custom jQuery script which adds scrolling.
And I still have 2 issues: it does not work in firefox and the main window still scrolls. Do you have any ideas how to solve it.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hm, load does not changed anything too.
I added custom mouse wheel scroll event and stop propagation for not scrolling parent element.
I only need to solve issue in firefox.

Comment: I just ran this page locally and `$('.foundry_modal').unbind('scroll');` works for me in Firefox. It was commented out in your code?

Comment: I uncommented the code for now. Its weird because that line is not working for me in latest firefox on Win at all.